# angular directive does not show in some cases

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

appreciate for your attention to this question.

I am pretty newbie in `angularjs` , I have some question when I use `angularjs directive`. Here is my problem.

I have a directive like this :

```
app.directive('dbmodeSelector', function() {
var tpl = ' <select class="atonFormSelect" ng-model="dbmode" ng-options="m for m in dbmodeList" ng-change="changeDbmode()" required> \
                    </select>';
return {
    transclude : true,
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
        dbmode : '=',
        dbmodeList : '=',
        changeAction : '&'
    },
    template : tpl,
    link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.changeDbmode = function() {
            var func = scope.changeAction();
            if(func) {
                func(scope.dbmode);
            }
        }
    }
}});
```

I use this directive like this :

```
<dbmode-selector dbmode="dbmode" dbmode-list="dbmodeList"></dbmode-selector>
```

It show correctly in some cases, when i look into this cases in chrome developer tools, the code of this directive look like this:

[correctly show case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfw62.png)

does not show correctly in other cases, chrome developer tools show the code like this :

[not correctly show case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7kLi.png)

The difference between them is the in the correct case, the `dbmode-selector` use the template as it's child element; in the wrong case, there is no child elements in `dbmode-selector`.

Question :

Why this difference ? Does the difference affect the visibility of this `dbmode-selector`.

Comment: when did it not show correctly? did you manually append it to html or use it in a way that is different from when it shows correctly?

Comment: In the second case, which is not working; you have passed `dbmode='appTair.dbmode'` Is that a valid modal? Because that's what you are using as ng-modal in your template.

Comment: the same way showing in the question. but different in the chrome developer tools 'elements' tab, like the image i paste in the question

Comment: @PM. this is a valid model, i log this in console, it show the correct value.

Comment: There may be a difference in the way you use the `<dbmode-selector>` directive that prevents it from being compiled by Angular. Can you show the parent markup for the non-working case?

Comment: Sorry, i check my project carefully, and I find i forgot to import the module of dbmode-selector to the angular app.